# set the default value of the new column to a value of an existing column after altering table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, alter-table

I have a table called "users".

```
id   name 
1    jack
2    lisa
```

I want to add a new column and set the default value of it to the value of the "id" column.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user_index INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT id;
```

since, the DEFAULT keyword, only accepts constant values the above code doesn't work.
**so, how can I set the default value of the new column to the value of "id" column?**

Comment: Look into using triggers.

Comment: Why do you want the same column twice in the table?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with just the `ALTER` statement. I would recommend performing the alteration and a copy in a transaction, where the copy would look something like:

```
UPDATE tableName SET user_index = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following demo SQL will do what you want.

```
/*
    Create and populate inital table
*/
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS set_user_index_as_id;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users; -- Note will drop the trigger
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `name` TEXT);
INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES('jack'),('lisa');
-- Show all columns of all rows of the initial table
SELECT * FROM users;
-- Add the new column with default value of -1 (should not interfere with id assuming it is never -1)


-- ONE-OFF SCHEMA CHANGE
-- Note sets default for rows previously added to default
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user_index INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1;
-- Show all columns of all rows after the alter
SELECT * FROM users;
-- Add the trigger to adjust the user_index value whenever a row is inserted
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS set_user_index_as_id AFTER INSERT ON users 
    BEGIN
        -- update rows that have not been updated i.e. user_index is -1 
        --    (so will adjust the original rows)
        UPDATE users SET user_index = id WHERE user_index = -1;
    END
;


-- Add some more rows (i.e.test the above)
INSERT INTO users ('name') VALUES('fred'),('mary');
-- Show Show all columns of all rows after the inserts
SELECT * FROM users;
```

This sets the default value to -1 (assuming that id will never be -1, it could be another value that id would never be that value) when ALTERing the table to add the column. A TRIGGER is then added that will update any rows that have -1 in the user_index column to be the same value as the id column whenever a new row is inserted.

- as all rows with -1 are updated the first insert after the trigger has been added will update any previously inserted rows (the default value is retrospectively applied to old rows)
- **Note** The above is a demo and has been designed to rerun, hence the DROP statements.

When run the queries, that show the progress, are :-

**After initial inserts**

[image]

**After the Alter**

[image]

**After the new inserts**

[image]

---

The above assumes that id is an alias of the rowid (what some term as AUTOINCREMENT) and hence the rows are in monotonically increasing order (increase from 1 to 2 to 3 ....).

However, say the first two rows had id values of 10 and 50 and then the new rows 51 and 52. These out of sequence values would be applied. A test very similar to the above, just changing the first insert to `INSERT INTO users VALUES(10,'jack'),(50,'lisa');`
has the final result, as expected, of :-

[image]